# C reading all data from pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork, child-process

My program creates child process and sets pipes to communicate with it. The problem occurs when i try to read data from the pipe. Since child process has ended (i use `wait` to ensure that) EOF should be on the end of the data stream thus ending the read (As in the man page for `pipe`). But instead `read` just freezes and waits for more data to come.
What am i missing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



void setfd(int *in, int *out) {
    dup2(out[1], 1);
    dup2(in[0], 0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int status;
    int pipe2ch[2], pipe2pr[2];
    char *newargv[] = {NULL, NULL};
    newargv[0] = argv[1];

    pipe(pipe2ch);
    pipe(pipe2pr);

    setfd(pipe2pr, pipe2ch);
    int a;
    if (!(a = fork())) {
        setfd(pipe2ch, pipe2pr);
        execve(newargv[0], newargv, NULL);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("hello!\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        char str;

        wait(&status);
        while (read(pipe2pr[0], &str, 1) > 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%c", str);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The parent process needs to close `pipe2pr[1]`. It's preventing itself from getting an EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since child process has ended (i use wait to ensure that) EOF should be on the end of the data stream thus ending the read (As in the man page for pipe).

I'm not sure what you've read to suggest that.  Or maybe it's your wording that I don't understand.  `EOF` is not a character on the stream.

> But instead read just freezes and waits for more data to come. What am i missing here?

Several things.  The most important one is probably that when a process forks, the child's copies of the parent's open file descriptors refer to the same entries in the kernel's underlying table of open files as the parent's do, each of which remains open until *all* handles on it are closed.  The child closes all its file descriptors when it exits, but ***both ends of both pipes remain open in the parent***, so end-of-file will not be signaled to readers.  Each process must close the pipe ends it doesn't use or is finished using.

Additionally, you should `read()` first, then `wait()`, for if the child process writes enough data to the pipe then it may block, and if the parent does not read until after the child exits then you'll have a deadlock.

Furthermore, I don't see any reason to dupe either pipe end onto the parent's standard streams (resulting in closing the original ones).  Just manipulate the pipes via their file descriptors, as you already half do.  If you want a stream interface to those, then use `fdopen()` to get one.